# Can Solr replicate external file fields file?

Tags: solr

I have several external file fields that get reloaded every hour. My solrconfig.xml has

```
<dataDir>${solr.data.basedir}/${solr.core.name}</dataDir>
```

and the external file field files are under this dir like `external_*`. With Solr replication, I can only replicate the index and the config files. Is the only option to separately reload these files on the slaves and then call `reloadCache` on all the slaves individually? Or can Solr replicate the external file fields files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr does not replicate ext file field files automatically, even if they are under the `<dataDir>` specified in solrconfig.xml. To replicate these files, we need to specify them under `confFiles` in the replication handler in solrconfig with relative paths.

My Solr conf dir (containing solrconfig.xml, synonyms.txt, etc.,) is at:

```
/var/solr/application-cores/List/conf
```

and my data dir containing the ext file field files is at:

```
/var/solr-data/List
```

so my confFiles looks like:

```
<str name="confFiles">solrconfig.xml,data-config.xml,schema.xml,stopwords.txt,synonyms.txt,elevate.xml,../../../../solr-data/List/external_eff_views</str>
```

No wild-cards are allowed, so I have to specify each ext file field file separately :-(.

Thanks to [link](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Working+with+External+Files+and+Processes) pointed out by @Jayendra, I can have the ext file fields reloaded on the slave after replication since I have set up listeners in solrconfig.xml like:

```
<listener event="newSearcher" class="org.apache.solr.schema.ExternalFileFieldReloader"/>
<listener event="firstSearcher" class="org.apache.solr.schema.ExternalFileFieldReloader"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Solr is able to [replicate the configuration files](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#How_are_configuration_files_replicated.3F) and the index.
Once the files are replicated, the Solr cores will be reloaded on the slaves and need not be done manually.

EDIT:-

The Location for the External files is the data folder which does get replicated.

Also for reloading the external files check [link](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Working+with+External+Files+and+Processes)

Comment: Guess you misread my qn. I want to know if Solr can replicate the files containing external file fields. i.e. files that match the glob pattern `${solr.data.basedir}/${solr.core.name}/external_*`.

Comment: ohk. the external files are places in the data folder and shouldn't they get replicated by default with the indexes ?

Comment: No, Solr does not replicate these files automatically, even though they are under the `data` folder.