# Solr unable to replicate external file (EFF) in data folder

Tags: solr

I am using ExternalFileField in solr, the file is updated on master using a script. Now I am trying to use solr.ReplicationHandler to copy the file on slave machines. I am providing relative path in confFile parameter.

```
<str name="confFiles">schema.xml,solrconfig.xml,../data/external_score </str>
```

This creates a folder "data" in my conf folder (solr/cores/core_name/conf/data/) of solr which has the external_score file. Instead it should put the file in "solr/cores/core_name/data/" 
folder.

Solr Documentation says you can only write files which are inside conf folder. But going through some of the stack overflow answers, they suggest otherwise.

This answer suggests this can be done
[Can Solr replicate external file fields file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286118/can-solr-replicate-external-file-fields-file)

If this is not possible, some alternate efficient solution is appreciated.
Solr Version : 5.5.2

Comment: [SOLR-4751 might have changed that behaviour](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4751) and was introduced around the same time as your linked answer was created.

Comment: conf and it's subdirectories do get loaded, in my case external field file has to be in the solr's data folder, where index is present. So what I need is a way to replicate files which are not present in the conf folder.

Comment: If I try to provide the relative path as "../../data/external_*" instead of the actual one (i.e., ../data/external_*) , I am getting this error :
Index fetch failed :org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: openNewSearcher called on closed core
 at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1570)
 at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1807)
 at org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher.openNewSearcherAndUpdateCommitPoint(IndexFetcher.java:717)

Comment: Can this be because replicationHandler is also trying to access the data folder, which is updating the index at that time?
Because after more experimenting I am able to replicate the file in a folder outside conf, but when I try to do the same for 'data' folder, I get the above mentioned exception.

Comment: @MatsLindh Can you suggest some alternate way, I have 10 masters and each master has 10 slaves, so I don't want to add a script in each solr machine. That's why replication felt like the intuitive solution.

Comment: I'm guess a symlink would work, but that would require initial setup by symlinking the file from your data dir to your conf dir, then replicating the file under the conf dir as supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the file rename for the confFiles list
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/index-replication.html#IndexReplication-Replicatingsolrconfig.xml

Provide the relative path for the file after ":" wrt. "conf" directory on slave eg. `../data/external_*:../../data/external_*`
This way it will be saved to one directory above on the slave ensuring the external data file to be replicated in "data" directory instead of "conf" directory.